# Xamarin Register As Assistant

Tags: c#, xamarin, replace, assistant

So, im trying to replace google assistant with my own assistant that i have made in Xamarin, and I cant seem to find out how to register my assistant, as an assistant (so that in the Assist & voice input page, I can set it to my app). Any ideas?

edit: I have tried googling it and i have turned up nothing, but at the same i dont know what im looking for... like is it code? is it a 'permission' I have to add? i just dont know.

Comment: I need it to be able to replace the google assistant, like you can do with Alexa as shown in this image. https://image.cnbcfm.com/api/v1/image/105189632-alexa.JPG?v=1525706126&w=740&h= only issue is my app wont show up in that list. im asking how do i get it to show in that list.

Comment: Has anyone got any ideas!! please!!!

Comment: can anyone help me??

Comment: please... anyone?? I still havent figured this out...

Comment: Did you achieved in xamarin Android or xamarin forms? And you want to achieved that like this link?https://developer.android.com/training/articles/assistant.html